# How to add and use Adobe Acrobat ActiveX Reader in Delphi 11

Tags: delphi, adobe, activex

I am Delphi beginner and I am creating a small contacts management application. I would like to be able to select a PDF file within Delphi and display it without having to open Adobe Acrobat Reader application. I followed the steps to import Adobe Reader ActiveX control, but after the import, I still can not see the control in my paletes to drop the control on my form. I see that the import was successful and there is AcroPDFLib.pas in Imports. I have attached pictures that shows the steps I took to add the control. Thanks for any help on this.[image: Step 1Step 2Step 3ActiveX showing in the imports]

With a list of PDF files in Delphi ListBox control, I want to select a PDF file from the list and then open it inside my application. The Adobe ActiveX does not show in my paletes.

Comment: Chrome based browsers like Microsoft Edge can display PDFs. As a result a lot fewer people are installing Acrobat Reader these days. Would suggest looking into using TEdgeBrowser.

Comment: Hi Brian. Thanks for your suggestion. I really would like something very light and integrated in my application. Anyway, I will give a try to this TEdgeBrowser and see if it fits my purpose.

Comment: Acrobat is by far not "_very light_" either.

Comment: Search for PDF reader components written in Delphi. TMS has new one, and there are a bunch of others available. You probably do not need to support 100% of the PDF file format, or even most of it, if all you want to do is show the file contents. I reverse-engineered the file format once before I found the spec; it took about 2 hours, and I was able to display all of the PDF files I needed to. But I concur with AmigoJack -- there's nothing "light" about this DLL (or ANY of Adobe's stuff).